# Get access to the file system in Windows Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I need store files in file system of Windows Azure.
I trying save files to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Files" + filename`, but it throw `IOException`. At my local server it works well.
How to do this on Windows Azure?

Comment: Are you using Cloud Services, Websites, or Virtual Machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change your application to make use of `Local Storage`. Check this link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx.

Furthermore, its a bad idea to persist files on the VM itself unless these are temporary files. If you need to persist the files, save them in blob storage instead.